# Can i insert qoutes in atable column with data type of text

Tags: mysql

Its like i want to enter html live coding from my front-end which connects to the back-end but when i use the anchors and images which includes the equal signs and quotations mysql give an arror

Comment: Hi, kindly put your code here.Let us know what you have tried

Comment: You can put anything you like in the column, and it will get a lot easier if you use sql Parameters- http://bobby-tables.com

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Comment: its like i created a CRUD web app whick is for posting news and any information (for fun) using PHP and MYSQL but the post content field i used atextarea on the front-end and gave it a data type of TEXT in the database but in i insert an image from the front-end it fails i used the image tag of HTML _(<img src="img.jpg">)_ such a tag but i failed to save into the database but when i remove that tag it saves

Comment: Thank you Alon but am new in this environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with this problem for a while as well. The easiest solution I found was to encode the html as base64 using `TO_BASE64()` and store that instead. Then when you want it back again simply decode it again.

Base64 encoding encodes a string into another string consisting only of 'normal' alphabetic characters so was perfect for storing strings containing characters that MySQL would otherwise interpret as escape characters

for example , to insert the text 'html = \' < > ' you would do something like

```
INSERT INTO test (html)
VALUES
   (TO_BASE64('html = \' < > ')   ) ;
```

This would actually store the string `aHRtbCA9ICcgPCA+IA==`

Then to get it back as real html we decode it using `FROM_BASE64()`

```
SELECT FROM_BASE64(html) AS html FROM test;
```

(this works from mysql ver 5.6)